# Little-o notation - why there's no $c$ in the definition?

Tags: asymptotics

http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~cshalizi/uADA/13/lectures/app-b.pdf

> The corresponding little-o means “is ultimately smaller than”: $f (n)
>  = o(1)$ means that $f (n)/c \to 0$ for any constant $c$.
>
> Recursively, $g (n) = o(f (n))$ means $g (n)/ f (n) = o(1)$, or $g (n)/ f (n) \to 0$

Notice that $f (n)
 = o(1)$ means $f (n)/c \to 0$ for any constant $c$.

But in the second case there's no $c$! Where did it 'go'? Shouldn't it be like

$g (n) = o(f (n))$ means $g (n)/ (f (n)) = o(1)$, or $g (n)/ (f (n)*c) \to 0$?

Comment: Literally, $f(n)=o(1)$ means $f(n)/1\to 0$, from which we deduce $f(c)/c\to 0$ for any non-constant $.$

Comment: If $f(n)\to 0$ then $f(n)/c\to 0$ for any $c$, and, of course, visa versa. Seems like a bad way to teach little-$o$. Ignore all the stuff about $c$.

Comment: The $c$ in the first definition is just stupid. Saying $f=o(1)$ just means $f\to0$.

Comment: That PDF is also wrong about what $O$ means - it defines it as $f(n)=O(1)$ if $f(n)\to c$ for some constant $c$. That is just blatantly wrong. (The little-$o$ definition is not technically wrong, just silly, but the big-$O$ definition goes against every other definition that I know of.)

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Preach!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a lot that is wrong in that PDF. The definition of big-$O$ is flat out wrong, for example.

The definition of little-$o$ is not wrong, per se, but it is certainly pointless. It seems like the writer is trying to create a parallel with the (broken) definition of big-$O$, but the constant $c$ is completely unnecessary for little-$o$.

I see from Wikipedia, though, this text, under "[Used in computer science](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Use_in_computer_science):"

> Informally, especially in computer science, the Big O notation often is permitted to be somewhat abused to describe an asymptotic tight bound where using Big Theta Θ notation might be more factually appropriate.

The PDF is slightly closer to this informal "tighter" usage of big-$O$, although even here, the PDF is giving a stronger definition.

Comment: The $c$ constant is unimportant because $f(x) = o(1)$ means $f(x) \to 0$ as $x\to 0$, and the limit doesn't change when we divide or multiply it by a constant, right?

Comment: Absolutely correct.